# Have count of records in one to many navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 4 tables 1-Cart 2-CartItems 3-CartItemDetails.
Tables 1 and 2 are one to many, tables 2 and 3 are one to many.

I want to retrieve some data from Table 1 and 2 and count of the CartItemDetails.

```cs
public class CartDto
{
    public long CartId { get; set; }       
    public int FinalPrice { get; set; }
    public int CartItemDetailCount { get; set; }
    public List<CartItemDto> CartItems { get; set; }
}

public class CartItemDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }        
    public long PackageId { get; set; }
    public string PackageTitle { get; set; }     
}
```

so I did this:

```cs
var cart = await _context.School_Carts                    
    .Include(p => p.CartItems)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.CartItemDetails)
    .Where(p => p.BrowserId == BrowserId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var result = new CartDto()
{
    FinalPrice = cart.FinalPrice,
    CartId = cart.Id,
    CartItemDetailCount = cart.CartItems.Select(p=>p.CartItemDetails.Count()),
    CartItems = cart.CartItems.Select(p => new CartItemDto
    {                       
        PackageTitle = p.Package.Title,
        Id = p.Id,
        PackageId = p.PackageId,
    }).ToList(),
};
```

How can I have the count in this situation?

Comment: Anyway your `CartDto` doesn't have `RequestedPrivate` property. Try to provide the entity classes too. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun: I want the CartItemDetail Count not CartItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe that you need to flatten the `CartItems` list to combine all items from the `CartItemDetails` into a single list via [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0).

```cs
CartItemDetailCount = cart.CartItems.SelectMany(x => x.CartItemDetails).Count()
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U2Jq4t)